# How private fields accessible on jsp page in struts 2.x?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Hello every one I am working with struts 2.x and very new for this framework . I follow list of tutorials and steps and my application working properly but there is one thing which is not clear to me Like when I declare one private field in my action class and using struts tag that private field is accessible to the jsp page . So how it happen that is not understandable for me:

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>


    <package name="default" namespace="/home" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="message" class="com.csc.action.MessageAction">
            <result name="hello">/hello.jsp</result>
            <result name="bye">/bye.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="add" class="com.csc.action.Mathaction">
            <result name="success">/hello.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/bye.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>



</struts>
```

MessageAction.java

```
package com.csc.action;

import com.csc.service.BussniessServ;

public class MessageAction {

    private String result;

    private String value;

    private String fstvalue;

     private String scndvalue;
    public String getFstvalue() {
        return fstvalue;
    }

    public void setFstvalue(String fstvalue) {
        this.fstvalue = fstvalue;
    }

    public String getScndvalue() {
        return scndvalue;
    }

    public void setScndvalue(String scndvalue) {
        this.scndvalue = scndvalue;
    }


    // method which get value from input parameter
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // method which show the value of input parameter
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // method which run as default and execute
    public String execute() {

        BussniessServ serv = new BussniessServ();
        setMessag(serv.Addition(fstvalue, scndvalue));
        return "hello";
    }

    // method to show message on jsp page
    public String getResult() {

        return result;
    }

    // method for save message
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:property value="result"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by accessible? You access that has accessors, getter or setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts uses reflection to find a method that returns that variable. For example, if you have a variable called `result` then Struts looks for a method called `getResult()` and calls it to obtain a value.

Also, if you want properties to be accessible in the JSP you have to make sure that you name these methods correctly. A property called "abc" would match the method getAbc() (unless it is a boolean, in which case would match the method isAbc() instead).

Comment: how reflection ?? as I know it works with class But here JSP page accessing the private field of action class.

Comment: @Bhagat Reflection can bypass accessibility modifiers.

Comment: @DaveNewton that i know but how it works with jsp page that is not clear to me.

Comment: @Bhagat What does the JSP part have to do with anything? OGNL expressions are evaluated against the value stack, and OGNL uses reflection to find values. The action is on the stack.

Comment: This used to be true, but isn't currently--there does not need to be a public accessor available, it's just best practice to follow JavaBean conventions and provide them.

Answer (score 2):

OGNL does not actually require accessors to be present, although this varies by version–earlier versions (~S2.0) required accessor methods. Later versions (~S2.1+) "helpfully" removed this restriction.

Public properties with private getters also works, although it's obviously pathological.

IMO it was a step backwards for data encapsulation.

It may be configurable in later/current versions of OGNL, I'm not sure.